# How to view document name of a print job

Tags: linux, logs, filenames, printing

How do I view the document name of a print job?  The closest I've come to the answer is with this command...

```
lpstat -W completed
```

...which displays several results with a timestamp, but no document name(s).

The reason I ask is because I want to locate a document I had created, printed, and saved to a name/location I do not know.  I only know the approximate time it was printed.